# Use Google App Script to find unique cell value in a row (including duplicated cell values)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hope you guys help me below question :

1. I have below 2 rows

[image]

2. I want to use google app script to pull out the unique values like : HTS, WDS, HH
3. So I write below codes :

- DATA =SHEET.GETRANGE("J2:O2").GETVALUES();
- UNIQUELIST=[];
- DATA.FOREACH(FUNCTION(X){
  IF(UNIQUELIST.indexOf(X[0]) === -1 && X[0]!="" ){
  UNIQUELIST.push(X[0]);}})

4. THE RESULT IS H,W. NOT AS WHAT LOOKING FOR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [Spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get the unique values of an array:

```
const uniqueArray = [...new Set(data)];
```

- [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) is used to convert the data into 1D array.

### Solution:

Adjust `'Sheet1'` to the name of your sheet:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // put the name of the sheet
  const data = sheet.getRange("J2:O2").getValues().flat();
  const uniqueArray = [...new Set(data)].filter(v=>v!='');
  console.log(uniqueArray)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Marios,
In case, if the Row values is like : HH, "blank cell ",HH, HTS
Could you advise me how not to get the blank cell, the desired values will be only like : HH,HTS

Comment: @KevinNgo thanks for your feedback. I updated my answer.